# Dependent boolean properties

Tags: c#

Lets say I have an object with two boolean properties:

```
public bool AdvancedMode{ get; set; }
public bool DumpDiagnostics{ get; set; }
```

The domain rules state that DumpDiagnostics is not allowed unless AdvancedMode is also true. So throughout the code you might see statements like this:

```
if( options.AdvancedMode && options.DumpDiagnostics ){ ... }
```

The problem with this is that it's easy to forget to add the check forAdvancedMode and accidentally check only for DumpDiagnostics.

```
if( options.DumpDiagnostics ) // Oh no!
```

So there are two solutions that I can think of:

#### Option 1: DumpDiagnostics only returns true when AdvancedMode is true.

```
public bool DumpDiagnostics
{ 
    get{ return AdvancedMode && _dumpDiagnostics; }
    set{ _dumpDiagnostics = value; }
}
```

#### Option 2: New property that reflects the condition I'm looking for

```
public bool CanDumpDiagnostics{ get{ return AdvancedMode && DumpDiagnostics; } }
```

#### Question: Which is better?

Option #1 seems pretty easy and less prone to error. There's always one authority on whether diagnostics can be dumped. But, it does change the set -> get semantics where you can assign DumpDiagnostics = true, followed by if( DumpDiagnostics ) where it returns false.

Option #2 is good because it isolates the logic and makes it clear what the purpose is. The biggest drawback I see with it is that it's still easy to just check for DumpDiagnostics instead of using the new CanDumpDiagnostics property.

p.s. I know it's an awkward title but couldn't come up with something more precise, feel free to modify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 2 makes more sense to me. I don't like properties which can be set but don't "take hold". I was going to suggest throwing an exception in the setter, but then remembered that you'd *also* have to throw an exception in the setter for `AdvancedMode` in case that was reset to false.

I'd rename `DumpDiagnostics` to something like `DiagnosticDumpRequested` to make it clearer that it doesn't guarantee it'll be honoured.

Comment: I like the naming convention "Requested" suffix.

Answer (score 4):

Alternately, pick option 3... turn the two booleans into an enum:

```
public enum Mode
{
    Normal,
    Advanced,
    AdvancedWithDiagnostics
}
```

(with names that are more appropriate for what you are doing)

**Addendum**:
If you want to go really "advanced", you can even use the following:

```
public enum Mode
{
    Normal = 0,
    Advanced = 1,
    AdvancedWithDiagnostics = 3
}
```

And use the following properties (again, pick better naming than mine!):

```
public Mode SelectedMode { get; set; }
public bool AdvancedMode { get { return (SelectedMode & 1) != 0; } }
public bool DumpDiagnostics { get { return (SelectedMode & 2) != 0; } }
```

Comment: This is what I would do, since there are really just three options, not four.

Comment: Here's why I don't like this option: This only works if there are exactly two properties. What happens when there's a new domain feature ClearCache? Now you've got Normal, Advanced, AdvancedWithDiagnostics, AdvancedWithDiagnosticeClearCache, AdvancedClearCache. Now add NotifyAdmins, now you have....and on it goes.

Comment: @Paul: you did not indicate you needed a generic solution to this kind of scenario... this does not solve every case of 'dependent booleans', but it does solve the one you highlighted...

Comment: @Paul: in the scenario you just indicated though I would personally opt for read-only properties 'bool AdvancedMode' and 'Features AdvancedFeatures' (an enum of the selected advanced features) and then rely on methods 'DisableAdvancedMode()' and 'EnableAdvancedMode(Features x)' to switch between the modes and select features only in the case of advanced mode.

Comment: @Paul: That's where [Flags] comes in, treating the enum as a set of flags. And logic in the property to validate combinations of flags are valid. Details of implementation are dependent on the details of the requirements.

Comment: @Richard: How does that actually solve the problem? You'd still have to check if( (SelectedMode & ( Advanced | Diagnostics ) ) != 0 ). This just makes it even more confusing and prone to errors. Enums are definitely not the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

What are the domain rules of the getting and setting the states?  In other words, it seems to me like the "set" function for DumpDiagnostics should also set the AdvancedMode.  If this is true, then just go with option 1 and you'll only need to check that DumpDiagnostics is set in the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is misleading. DumpDiagnostics should not be equal to AdvancedMode && DumpDiagnostics. I would go with option 2